# A separate class, or maybe placing in a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have the following fragment:

[image]

I wonder if I should create a separate class that will be responsible for calculations as in this case:

```
public class Conventional implements Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division {

    private double firstNumber;
    private double secondNumber;

    public Conventional(int  firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(int firstNumber, float secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(float firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(int firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(double firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(float firstNumber, float secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(float firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(double firstNumber, float secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public Conventional(double  firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }
}
```

Or maybe all the elements in the Conventional class should I put in the fragment class?

What solution is correct?

Comment: In another class

Comment: Yes, putting logic like this in its own class makes the code more modular.